# Why does `summarize` drop a group?

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, summarize

I'm fooling around with `babynames` pkg. A `group_by` command works, but after the `summarize`, one of the groups is dropped from the group list.

```
library(babynames)
babynames[1:10000, ] %>% group_by(year, name) %>% head(1)

# A tibble: 1 x 5
# Groups:   year, name [1]
   year   sex  name     n       prop
  <dbl> <chr> <chr> <int>      <dbl>
1  1880     F  Mary  7065 0.07238433
```

This is fine---two groups, `year, name`. But after a summarize (which respects the groups correctly), the `name` group is dropped. Am I missing an easy mistake?

```
babynames[1:10000, ] %>% 
    group_by(year, name) %>% 
    summarise(n = sum(n)) %>% head(1)

# A tibble: 1 x 3
# Groups:   year [1]
   year  name     n
  <dbl> <chr> <int>
1  1880 Aaron   102
```

More info, in case it's relevant:

```
R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS  10.13.2
dplyr_0.7.4
```

Comment: `?summarise`: "One grouping level will be dropped.". Or more explicit in [the vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/dplyr.html): "When you group by multiple variables, each summary peels off one level of the grouping."

Comment: In a way, it makes sense to drop a variable after summarising. Once you've summarised, you've already sort of narrowed-down the grouping variables. In other words, if you checked `sum(!duplicated(babynames[1:10000, c("name", "year")]))`, you would get the same value as the number of rows you would get if you did `babynames[1:10000, ] %>% group_by(year, name) %>% summarise(n = sum(n))`. In other words, you don't need multiple columns at that level for "uniqueness", which is what we usually look at in a grouping variable.

Comment: Sure, but for the operations I do afterward, I want my `group` to be `name`, not `year`. So to avoid my mistake, you have to know (a) a group will be dropped after summarizing and (b) the group to be dropped is the last group in the `group_by` call. It makes sense to do it this way, but it doesn't warn you that it's happening.

Comment: @JesseTweedle, perhaps it's worth exploring whether there's an issue for it, and if not, raise an issue so that the documentation can be more informative....

Comment: There is a recent, closed issue on this topic: [dplyr::summarise removes a grouping variable](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/3315) where documentation was discussed, but it seems to be concluded that the docs are OK. Personally I think the help text could be more explicit, e.g. about the order of in which grouping variables are dropped.

Comment: Another issue where this undocumented order of dropping is discussed: [data is still grouped after a summarize (but not by original set of columns)](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2963): "This is just one more convention for users to have to memorize and get confused on."; "`help(summarize)` says "One grouping level will be dropped" _how is the user to know which one_?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The behavior is noted in the documentation see `?summarise` **Value** section:

> **Value**
>   An object of the same class as `.data`. One grouping level will be dropped.

---

In contrast, `mutate` does *not* drop any grouping levels:

> **Value**: An object of the same class as `.data`.

Comment: The behaviour is noted, but it doesn't answer the question (what is the reason for the drop).

Comment: Daang, I didn't realize. I think I've been assuming all the operations respect the groups before and after.

Comment: ^to add to that. I take the "reason" to be "bc Hadley wants it that way". The docs say "to make it easy to progressively roll up a dataset", but it automatically drops the groups in order that you've specified, which most ppl wouldn't realize (unless you've noticed an error in your code or have seen that line in the docs). I'll have to pay closer attention in the future. 

Comment: @Psidom to be clear, I wasn't criticizing your response, I was just stating that it remains an open question.