Why does dplyr::tally() remove last grouping variable from output?
When running dplyr::tally() on a grouped data.frame, then the last grouping variable will be removed from the "Groups". I'm sure that this is intended behaviour but I don't understand why and where this is documented. Any ideas?
library(dplyr) # 1.0.10

# single grouping variable returns ungrouped output
starwars %>%
  group_by(species) %>%
  tally() %>%
  groups()

#> list()

# three grouping variables return output grouped by first and second group
starwars %>%
  group_by(species, eye_color, skin_color) %>%
  tally() %>%
  groups()

#> [[1]]
#> species
#>
#> [[2]]
#> eye_color


Here's a related question about why summarize (and by extension tally) drop the last grouping variable: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48489219/why-does-summarize-drop-a-group. In the case that something is grouped by just one variable, then that dropping behavior is the only thing that makes the result a summary -- otherwise the output would match the output of mutate on grouped data, with just as many rows as the input.

As @Konrad Rudolph mentioned tally internally calls summarise whose default behavior is to drop last grouping value.
From ?summarise

.groups   [Experimental] Grouping structure of the result.
"drop_last": dropping the last level of grouping. This was the only
supported option before version 1.0.0.
"drop": All levels of grouping are dropped.
"keep": Same grouping structure as .data.
"rowwise": Each row is its own group.

Additionally,

When .groups is not specified, it is chosen based on the number of
rows of the results:
If all the results have 1 row, you get "drop_last

Since in your case you are getting 1 row per group drop_last behavior is used.
